# Should I include this piece in the vowel? [spectrogram]

Tags: phonetics, praat, acoustic-analysis, sociophonetics

I'm trying to measure vowel length in 'beat", utterance-final. Should I place the marker where it is now or further to the right, as there is some activity there?

[image: spectrogram and oscillogram of the word 'beat']

Answer (score 1):

It seems good. The vocal folds continue to vibrate a little bit after your boundary, even though the tongue and the lips were already articulating a stop, but it is just a coarticulation phenomenon. Yet, your burst seems very long and energetic for a [b].

Comment: Thank you. How do you know that the stop is already being articulated? Is it the F2 or the amplitude? Can you tell what that vertical stripe in the middle of the spectrogram is?

When it comes to the burst, do you think I should include it in the vowel? Almost all of the /b/ stops I analyze look like this, so I follow the convention in one of the books and I mark the beginning of the vowel just before the first obvious vowelly cycle.

Comment: @Grzegorz There is no longer formants, so it means that vocal resonance was stopped. In the release part, the first peak corresponds to your burst but afterwards it is the onset of your vowel.

Comment: Look at this course: http://ec-concord.ied.edu.hk/phonetics_and_phonology/wordpress/learning_website/chapter_3_consonants_new.htm